# ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy (Linking Host_id to Tour_id)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, devise

As a newbee to ROR I am struggling with an Associations between a Host (using devise gem) and Tour product.

The host can login and create tours under which should display under their show.html.erb ...../hosts/1

Although I get error messaging shown up on the show.html.erb

```
#<Host:0x007f91824e91a0>
#<Tour:0x007f91824e81d8>
<Tour::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f91824f5798>
Verification
```

As above tried various lines of code to manage the output but to no success.

**show.html.erb** (for hosts)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="center">

    </div>

    <% if @tours = Tour.find(params[:id]).blank? %>
        <p>There are NOT any TOURS currently in the system.</p>
    <% else %>
        <p>These are the current TOURS in our system</p>

    <ul class = "tours">
        <% @tours = Tour.find do |t| %>
        <li><%= link_to @host.tours, :action => "show", :tours => t.text -%></li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>

    <% end %>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Verification</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <%= @host.email %><br>
            Phone Number here andmpre
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: screenshot of the show.html.erb for hosts with error messages]

- The rule to find tours is working and displays that their are tours in our system.
- Furthemore I cannot use <% @tours = Tour.**each** do |t| %> .. displays this error message undefined method `each' for # . So I always change it back to'find'
- Currently under hosts/1 there should be about 5 tours to be shown.

**hosts.controller.rb**

*(I have # comments for ways I have tried various relations to no success)*

```
class HostsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_host, only: [ :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def show
        @host = Host.find(params[:id]) #original working code
        #@host = Host.find_by id: (params[:id])
        #@host = Host.find(params[:id]).tours
        #@tours = Host.find(params[:id]).tours
        #@host = Tour.find(params[:id]).host
    end

private

    def host_params
        params.require(:host_id).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

**tours_controller.rb**

```
class ToursController < ApplicationController
    #before_action :set_tour, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :create]
    before_action :authenticate_host!, except: [:create]
    before_action :host_session

    def index
        #@tours = current_host.tours
        @tours = Tour.all
    end

    def show
        @tour = Tour.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        @tour = Tour.new
        @hosts = Host.all #new line of code
    end

    def edit
        @tour = Tour.find(params[:id])
        @hosts = Host.all #new line of code
    end

    def create
        @tour = Tour.new(tour_params)

        if @tour.save
            redirect_to @tour
        else
            @hosts = Host.all #new line of code
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def update
        @tour = Tour.find(params[:id])

        if @tour.update(tour_params)
            redirect_to @tour
        else
            @hosts = Host.all #new line of code
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @tour = Tour.find(params[:id])
        @tour.destroy

        redirect_to tours_path
    end

    private
        def tour_params
            params.require(:tour).permit(:title, :text)
        end
end
```

**migrate `xxxx_create_tours.rb`**

```
class CreateTours < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tours do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :text
      t.column :host_id, :integer #new line of code
      t.references :host, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_foreign_key :tours, :hosts
    add_index :tours, [:host_id, :created_at]
  end
end
```

**migrate `xxx_devise_create_hosts.rb`**

```
class DeviseCreateHosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:hosts) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :hosts, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :hosts, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :hosts, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :hosts, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

Basics of the error summary
* need to show related tours under a host using show.html.erb
* provide correct relations

I have looked through Hartl, http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/ , http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-views.htm and many other sources and no success.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: the error is I cannot get to display the related tours under the host.id at all, all that is showing is proxy codes. plus it only show the same tour under each hosts/1 (which should show have 3 unique tours) and hosts/2  (which should show have 2 unique tours). The host can only create a new tour when they logged in and then is should be showing under the host profile page

Comment: error occur because you are using `find` method which return only single object if you want to get multiple object you have to use `where` method of active record

Comment: okay done that to the show.html.erb for hosts - but no tours show up now.. 
 <% if [at]tours = Tour.where(params[:id]).blank? %>
  <p>There are NOT any TOURS currently in the system.</p>
 <% else %>
  <p>These are the current TOURS in our system</p>
  
 <ul class = "Tour">
     <% [at]tours = Tour.where do |tour| %>
     <li><%= link_to tour.title, tour_path(tour) %></li>
     <% end %>
 </ul>

do i have to change it in the controller?

Comment: what you do in view ?

Comment: in tours main view I use index.html 
<h1>Index TOURS</h1>

<%= link_to 'New Tour', new_tour_path %>
 
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Text</th>
  </tr>
 
  <% [at]tours.each do |tour| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= tour.title %></td>
      <td><%= tour.text %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', tour_path(tour) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_tour_path(tour) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', tour_path(tour),
              method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>

this shows all tours

Comment: here you got an error?

Comment: should a line like this somehow get into my schema.rb
add_index "tours", ["host_id"], name: "index_tours_on_host_id" 
*just a thought

Comment: add screenshot to the post for the hosts show.html.erb

Comment: if you are using where than you get `ActiveRecord::Relation` Array object you have to iterate on it with each

Comment: add me to skype @biggztyle .. might be helpful ?

Comment: are you able to send the file again @uzaif